# Spring mvc, fileds not in form will get cleared because of null value

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, data-binding, modelattribute

I have a simple POJO:

```
@Document(collection = "questions")
public class Question {

    private String title;

    private Date createdAt;
    //..... all the getter and setters
}
```

I did not add the createdAt on the edit form, because it should not be changed after creation. But the update controller method will get a null value in createdAt due to the binding.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
public String update(@Valid Question question, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, question);
        return "questions/update";
    }
    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    questionRepository.save(question);
    return "redirect:/questions/"
            + encodeUrlPathSegment(question.getId().toString(),
                    httpServletRequest);
}
```

So after updating the Question, the createdAt field will get cleared. Any idea how to solve it? I don't want to create another class without createdAt field and do the update.

Comment: `createdAt` is not cleared. A new instance of `Question` is created every time `update()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden field in your form, pre-populated with createdAt.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it is a good way as if some people want to change the createdAt, he just need to remove the hidden attribute(via developer tools, eg.) in browser and change the value.